# SAX parser not reading part of node content

Tags: java, sax, double-quotes

I have a XML file created by MS Excel with elements like this:

```
   <Row ss:Height="18.75">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s24"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s25"><Data ss:Type="String">22. Department&quot;GS &quot;NAES &quot;ABCDEF&quot;in Brucele</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s24"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s24"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s24"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s259"/>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:Height="45">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s97"><Data ss:Type="String">1210.1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s98"><Data ss:Type="String">Boss of Department&quot;GS &quot;NAES &quot;ABCDEF&quot;in Brucele</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s99"><Data ss:Type="String">керівник</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s223"><Data ss:Type="Number">22</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s100"><Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s276"><Data ss:Type="String">Petrov ivan</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
```

When second cell of first row is read by function:

```
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length){
 String str = new String(ch, start, length);
...
}
```

`str` contains only this part "22. Department" of textnode.

Comment: Which parameters you pass to `characters` method? And what result you want to have?

Answer (score 1):

You should collect the string in `characters()`, because this method can be called multiple times for the content between a tag pair. I your example the entity `&quot;` forces the parser to multiple calls of `characters()`. Note: The parser may call special callbacks for entities.

Thus, you should use an instance variable for the characters in your parser where you append the strings. You must clear its content if a new element starts.